# Cake baking issues, calling non-static method

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I recently came back to a project I haven't worked on for a few months and am getting this error:

> Non-static method AppController::isAdmin() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context [APP/View/Elements/auth_menu_new.ctp

`isAdmin` isn't defined statically, the definition:

```
public function isAdmin() {
$r = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.group_id'); //line 80
if ($r == 1)
    return true;

return false;
}
```

Calling it like so:

```
                   <?php if (AppController::isAdmin()) { ?>
                    <li><a href="/users">Users</a></li>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Any ideas? If i define the function as static I cant use `$this`.

When I call the function by creating a new instance like so:

```
<?php
$aci = new AppController();
die($aci->isAdmin());
?>
```

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function read() on a non-object in /var/www/app/Controller/AppController.php on line 80

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you calling this function? Can you post where you instantiate and call this function? The function definition alone isn't enough to help you.

Comment: Yeah, calling it like so:
`<?php if (AppController::isAdmin()) { ?>`

Comment: The question is not clear. You either use an instance to invoke a method or call it statically. There is no magic here

Comment: I'm trying to call it statically as shown. When I do this I end up with the "should not be called statically" error.

Comment: Because it's not a static method - so it should not be called statically.

Comment: You cant call it statically because it's not defined as static.

Comment: So if I define the function statically I get this error:
`Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /var/www/app/Controller/AppController.php on line 80`
Where line 80 is the session read.

Comment: That's right - because static functions don't have references to `$this`

Comment: If I remove the static keyword then call it like so:
`<?php
$aci = new AppController();
die($aci->isAdmin());
?>`
I receive the following error:
`Fatal error: Call to a member function read() on a non-object in /var/www/app/Controller/AppController.php on line 80`
So how do I proceed to read the session in cake?

Comment: Well, where does that `$this->Session` come from?

Comment: You should edit your post and provide more code.

Comment: The session component of cake. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html

Comment: Whirlwind, what code do you want? I've included all the code I think I need?

Comment: Everything around <?php if (AppController::isAdmin()) { ?> Also it would be helpful if you make a notice from which files/classes/controllers you are running your code.

Comment: Ah dont worry, think I've kind of resolved it. Instead of reading the session using the SessionComponent I'm using AuthComponent like so: `AuthComponent::user('group_id')`. It appears to work.